# How to do something to each file in a directory with a batch script

Tags: windows, file, loops, batch-file, cmd

How do you iterate over each file in a directory with a .bat or .cmd file?

For simplicity please provide an answer that just echoes the filename or file path.

Answer (score 395, accepted):

Command line usage:

```
for /f %f in ('dir /b c:\') do echo %f
```

Batch file usage:

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /b c:\') do echo %%f
```

**Update**: if the directory contains files with space in the names, you need to change the delimiter the `for /f` command is using. for example, you can use the pipe char.

```
for /f "delims=|" %%f in ('dir /b c:\') do echo %%f
```

**Update 2**: (quick one year and a half after the original answer :-)) If the directory name itself has a space in the name, you can use the `usebackq` option on the `for`:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f in (`dir /b "c:\program files"`) do echo %%f
```

And if you need to use output redirection or command piping, use the escape char (`^`):

```
for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f in (`dir /b "c:\program files" ^| findstr /i microsoft`) do echo %%f
```

Comment: I tried to enumerate the files in a current directory with this command [ for /f %%f in ('dir /b .') do echo %%f ].. Unfortunately files with spaces had their name printed up to their first space.. ?
Thanks

Comment: At least for some commands, the file variable should be enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: This is also useful: How to do multiple things to each file in a directory with a batch script http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304867/how-to-do-multiple-things-to-each-file-in-a-directory-with-a-batch-script?lq=1

Comment: Why is the `/f` needed after the `for`?  According to the help docs, the `/f` flag opens and reads each file.  Is that needed to echo or rename files?

Comment: The `/f` after `FOR` restricts it to files. Similarly, `/d` restricts to directories (folders) and `/r` instructs it to be recursive.

Comment: +1 This is a living answer, continuously attended to; many thanks.

Comment: Why not just use "tokens=*" instead of "delims=|" for spaces?

Comment: I ran this: `C:\Program Files>for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f in ('dir /b "c:\program files"') do echo %%f` but I always get the output message "%%f was unexpected at this time.". Why? What's wrong?

Comment: %% is for use in scripts. if you are just running a command in the cmd, use %f instead

Comment: Hi, I think you should complement your answer by adding the recommendation to change dir (cd) into the files folder. This is due to %f not having full path, and as so, operations in the files aren't accessed from anywhere.

Comment: That is true. `dir /b` returns only the file name. It's trivial to use concatenation to add the directory name in the operation after `do` though. No need to change to the directory.

Comment: what if you want to a batch file to iterate over .dwg files in a directory - where both the directory and the filename have spaces. This is my attempt: ----->           for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f in ('dir /b "c:\program files\*.DWG"') do echo %%f                          -------> will that work?

Comment: `for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f in ('dir /b "c:\program files\*.DWG"') do echo %%f` -> this should work, though I don't have a Windows machine right now to verify.

Comment: When I run the Update2 script from a batch file, it only echoes `dir /b "c:\program files"` not the actual list of files :(

Comment: Just realized you have to use back quotes... Instead of `'dir /b "c:\program files"'` it should be `\`dir /b "c:\program files"\``

Comment: @endavid: I edited the answer to fix the back quotes.  Thanks for catching that.  I was having the same problem.

Comment: @GuitarPicker: The back quotes are only used if you have "usebackq" as an option, otherwise you use single quotes. So it works for the examples in Edit 2 but breaks the original answer.

Comment: It was fun to watch over the years how people would fight whether it should be backquotes or straight single quotes. :-)

Comment: ` => The system cannot find the file `dir.

Comment: For full paths in subdirs use 'dir /b /s'

Comment: BTW For a path with spaces you can just surround the path with double quotes, and then there is no need for backticks

Comment: Nice Job. Only suggestion is that you add quotation marks around %%f   i.e.```do echo "%%f`"``` If you don't have quotation marks, you will be trying to execute a command with a space in it. For example ```start "hello world.bat" ``` is a valid command, but ```start hello world.bat``` is not.

Comment: How to modify the command to do only on files with a given extension ?

Comment: @Olorin change ```dir /b "c:\program files"``` to something like ```dir /b "c:\program files\*.png"```.

Comment: My file name contained non-ASCII characters. I ended up adding `chcp 65001 &&` in front of the command. The subdirectory was not being passed so I added /s to the dir command and put the last %%f between double quotation marks.

Answer (score 141):

Alternatively, use:

```
forfiles /s /m *.png /c "cmd /c echo @path"
```

The forfiles command is available in Windows Vista and up.

Comment: it was difficult using paths with spaces in the 2nd cmd shell.
In the end I adjusted %PATH% env var to get the job done.
But thanks. helpful

Comment: works very well for example: forfiles /s /m *.bak /c "cmd /c 7za.exe a  @path.7z @path"

Comment: Why do you call another external program, cmd here? I have cmd restricted (however, batch files are working and powershell is also here).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles

Answer (score 96):

Easiest method:

From Command Line, use:

```
for %f in (*.*) do echo %f
```

From a Batch File (double up the % percent signs):

```
for %%f in (*.*) do echo %%f
```

From a Batch File with folder specified as 1st parameter:

```
for %%f in (%1\*.*) do echo %%f
```

Comment: not just easiest, but also significantly more elegant compared to evaluating the `dir /B` output with `for`.

Comment: Add a /r before the %f to recurse subdirectories

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer

Answer (score 39):

Use

```
for /r path %%var in (*.*) do some_command %%var
```

with:

- path being the starting path.
- %%var being some identifier.
- *.* being a filemask OR the contents of a variable.
- some_command being the command to execute with the path and var concatenated as parameters.

Comment: I get the error: `%%var was unexpected at this time.` Can you give an exact example? I tried a bunch of variations of `for /r . %%var in (*.*) do echo %%var`

Comment: For some strange reason, the variable name is restricted to one character.

Comment: Can we use different smileys for different results?

Answer (score 10):

Another way:

```
for %f in (*.mp4) do call ffmpeg -i "%~f" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "%~nf.avi"
```

Comment: what "~nf" stands for?

Comment: @JudgeDredd `"%~nf"` stands for name of the file without extension, where `f` is the name of the variable specified in `for` part. Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490909(v=technet.10)

Answer (score 0):

I had some malware that marked all files in a directory as hidden/system/readonly. If anyone else finds themselves in this situation, cd into the directory and run `for /f "delims=|" %f in ('forfiles') do attrib -s -h -r %f`.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Your answer doesn't really answer the question very well if they don't understand the context of the line given. You didn't need to do this anyway as ATTRIB has command line flags to run through sub-directories and process all files.

`ATTRIB -S -H -R /S /D *.*` (/S Processes files in sub-directories, /D processes folders too)