# Iterating through a folder using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder containing 1000+ xml files. I need to modify these xml files, for which I am using xslt.

Now the problem that I am facing is that I want to use batch script to do this modification recursively for all the xml files in the folder, rather than doing it manually. How can I do it using batch script?

It would be helpful if anybody could tell me how can I read all the xml files present in a folder and copy them to another folder with the same name.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180741/how-to-do-something-to-each-file-in-a-directory-with-a-batch-script and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138497/batch-scripting-iterating-over-files-in-a-directory

Answer (score 6):

Transformation:

```
for /r c:\your_root_folder\ %f in (*.xml) do your_transform_command %f
```

Copy:

```
copy *.xml c:\your_target_folder\.
```

Comment: NOTE: You'll need to use `%%f` inside a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using DOS batch ...

A simple `copy` operation will work:

```
prompt> copy *.xml destinationDir
```

To loop and process files individually, we use:

```
for %%R in (*) do (
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

read this

`HELP XCOPY`,

and this

`HELP FOR`.

and try this

`XCOPY \source\*.xml \destination /S`

and try this

`FOR %a IN (\source\*.xml) DO echo %a`

and now read

`HELP CALL`

and read

`HELP SET`

and try this

`FOR %a in (\source\*.xml) DO CALL youraction %~na`

and by the time you understand what happened you are ready to achieve your goal.