# How to let batch script browse through folders?

Tags: batch-file, iterator

I have a script, that modifies specific files all the time.

```
findstr /s /m "BLABLABLA" C:\BLABLABLA\*.BLA > bla.bla
if %errorlevel%=="0" (
    BLABLABLA
)
```

I know that "Blabla" isn't very transparent...

How to make a BAT file. That finds every file with `BLA` extension, that contains `BLABLABLA` in every place, every folder, every partition.
[Iterating through a folder using batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145782/iterating-through-a-folder-using-batch-script) It does work only in 1 folder.

Comment: Ok to clarify the asker wants to process all files containing "BLABLABLA"

Comment: Oh, you mean that. Why didn't you just tell, and started to complicate everything. *busy with editing*.

Comment: Please give better details in your question.  Do you want to find something like *.txt files on a set of drive letters?  The files have to contain a "String" so I assume they need to be text format files, right?  Does the script have to detect all drive letters?  What if one is a DVD disk in a DVD drive?  Can you set the list of drive letters in the batch file?

Comment: Yes. Files that contain specific strig, but not only .txt files, I want to scan all files that can be opened by notepad. All drive letters, including DVD disc and USBs. I would like to keep user away from setting list of drives to scan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@echo off

setlocal

set DRIVES=C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

(for %%d in (%DRIVES%) do (
  if exist "%%d:\" (
    pushd "%%d:\"
    for /r %%f in (*.BLA) do (
      findstr /m "BLABLABLA" "%%~f" && (
        BLABLABLA
      )
    )
    popd
  )
)) > bla.bla
```

A somewhat more elegant approach would enumerate the local drives via WMI:

```
@echo off

setlocal

(for /f %%d in (
  'wmic logicaldisk where drivetype^=3 get caption ^| find ":"'
) do (
  pushd "%%d\"
  for /r %%f in (*.BLA) do (
    findstr /m "BLABLABLA" "%%~f" && (
      BLABLABLA
    )
  )
  popd
)) > bla.bla
```

Comment: Ok, but. I want to make changes to *.BLA files, where is it possible to do this?

Comment: @RikTelner Your original question is not clear as to what you want to actually do so you must live with some sort of vagueness in answers. Because you yourself are being overly vague on the subject of what the error level is used for. Its not apparent form your question that you actually want to modify files since your demo only modifies ONE file while reading many. The reason I didn't suggest an answer much like the one above is that i didn't understand what the error checking is for. But id dint catch that your new description either.

Comment: Dear Ansgar, your script works correctly. But it finds all .BLA files, not only the ones that contain "BLABLABLA".

Comment: Yes but your demo has an interdiction many to one how on earth are we supposed to understand that it is a many to many interdiction but you just dont know how to do that?

Comment: Yes fine but then type that question in English don't let us guess what you think.

Comment: I bet on my head, that my post is written in English. 8/

Comment: @RikTelner The proposed solutions only list files with the extension `.BLA` and only if they contain a string "BLABLABLA". If you get other files, you're doing something differently from what I suggested.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I just directly copied and changed commando, file and extension.

Comment: @RikTelner Then you'll get only .BLA files containing the string "BLABLABLA".

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Ehm, it works for `.BLA` but doesn't works for `.BAT` although I changed script for it.

Comment: @RikTelner Then the .bat files don't contain the string "BLABLABLA".

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers It did, it really did. But, someone else provided answer, thank you for help though. You helped much aswell.

Comment: The script worked fine even with `.bat` files when I tested it. If you can't disclose more details, this is as much help as I can provide.

Comment: Sorry, I am dumb >,< if it workes correctly for you, that means I'd messed up. I try to figure out.

Comment: Yep, I messed it up. My fault, I am so dumb. It works now. Thank you. Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Sorry for causing problems; and thank you very much once again.

Answer (score 2):

> finds every file with BLA extension,
>
> that contains BLABLABLA
>
> in every [...], every folder, every partition

try:

```
 for %%i in (C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do findstr /lsimpc:"BLABLABLA" "%%i:\*.BLA" 2>nul
```

> in every place, [...]

specify: `place`

Comment: Works exactly how I wanted! You answered 3 of my questions correctly. You are really good! Thank you, it works very good, and how as I wanted. Could you provide me links to some information about %%i %%f etc. ? Because these are ones that I doesn't know yet, and I can't Google it since Google doesn't accept percentage signes.

Comment: Is there possibility to make file names, print in file? Changing `>nul` to `>result.txt` doesn't work. Since `result.txt` stays empty, even if prompt says there is one.

Comment: Try this: `for %%i in (C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do findstr /lsimpc:"BLABLABLA" "%%i:\*.BLA" >result.txt 2>nul`. Basic help about loop parameters you can find at the command line `for /?`, more advanced help ... in the net, eg. [dostips](http://dostips.com).

Comment: Thank you for your help, but someone already helpfully answered the question. Thanks for trying helping though, that's why you get upvotes. Thanks for link, helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing are you looking for something like:

```
@echo off

for /r %%f in (*.bla) do (
    for /f %%i in ('findstr /m "BLABLABLA" "%%~f"') do (
        echo do something to "%%~f"
    )
)
```

add the drive letter resolution form Ansgar Wiechers post

Comment: There's no need for the inner loop if you're not processing the output anyway. Just do `findstr /m "BLABLABLA" "%%~f" && (...)`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Yes, your right, the lines were just copy pasted form something that actually does need that. Mostly this answer is redundant now anyway because you updated yours.