# How to do multiple things to each file in a directory with a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

This is a direct extension of this question:

[How to do something to each file in a directory with a batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180741/how-to-do-something-to-each-file-in-a-directory-with-a-batch-script)

From the above I leaned how to execute a command for every file in a folder.

How do you execute MULTIPLE commands for each file?  I want to first use lame to compress the file, then MOVE the original file to a different directory

This is what I have so far:

```
FOR /r cutAndPendingCompression %%f IN (*.*) DO lame %%f compressed\%%~nf -m m -b 16 --vbr-new -V 9 --scale 2.5
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This did it

```
FOR /r cutAndPendingCompression %%f IN (*.*) DO (
lame %%f compressed\%%~nf -m m -b 16 --vbr-new -V 9 --scale 2.5
move %%f cut\%%~nf
)
```