# Trying to process files using a Batch. No output, Nothing happens

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I'm trying to pass files one by one(I have to dot that since executable only accepts one file at a time).  So, in my batch I have follwoing:

```
FOR /F %file IN ('dir /b /s *.css') DO CALL myExecutable.exe %file
```

I should see out files in same directory but nothing happens, no errors are displayed either. 
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several mistakes in your example:

- `FOR` parameter name is a single letter only
- `CALL` is used to call another batch file or a subroutine in the existing batch file, not executables
- the `FOR` parameter should be referenced with two %, when in batch file
- you need to use a non-space delimiter, if the directory you run this command in or any subdirectory, or if any of the files has a space in the name

With these in mind, here's the right command you should be using:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f in (`dir /b /s *.css`) do myexecutable.exe "%%f"
```

Here's [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180741/how-to-do-something-to-each-file-in-a-directory-with-a-batch-script/180749#180749) to a similar SO question, where I give more details on using `FOR` to process all files in a directory.

Comment: technically, you don't need the `usebackq` in your particular scenario, but it's a good habit to have.

Comment: thank you this made it work. except that I had to exclude "usebackq delims=|". it didn't work, it started to process 'dir' 'b' as actual file names. once it was removed, everything works.