# How to get files in a directory including all subdirectories files?

Tags: batch-file, directory, dos

I need to get all files that are inside a dir including files that are inside all dirs.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180741/how-to-do-something-to-each-file-in-a-directory-with-a-batch-script) that gets all files of the dir, but it is for the current level files and don't goes any deeper.

Maybe there is already a built-in function to do this?

Comment: The second answer to the linked post has the /r switch.  That should do as you need.

Comment: @akf thanks, that totally worked, I just changed the name of `%%var` and magically it worked

Comment: @ajax333221, isn't `dir /s` a whole lot easier?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To list all files in the current directory and sub-directories, use:

```
dir /s
```

Comment: I wish the flag was more obvious, like `/r` for recursive.