# Batch file to loop over files and run a command

Tags: file, loops, batch-file, command

I've read probably 20 stacks and have tried to mash together an answer and it just isn't coming together.
I need to loop over a set of files in a directory, running a command on them as I go, and log the output. (Ideally a text compare on the output from the command would be nice, but I'm fine to read through the log.)
PROBLEM: The following command doesn't output the result to the txt file. It outputs the "dumpbin /HEADERS...." into the txt. The command itself is not being run.

```
for %%f in ('dir /b "\\machine\c$\Program Files (x86)\software\bin64\*"') do (dumpbin /HEADERS %%f | find "machine")
```

Then I'm running `look.bat >>foo.txt`

The above is meant to pump out either *32bit word machine* or *8664 machine (x64)* depending on the file when run from VS Command prompt.

I've also tried the following with no difference.

```
for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f in ('dir /b "\\machine\c$\Program Files (x86)\software\bin64\*"') do (dumpbin /HEADERS %%f | find "machine")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do something to each file in a directory with a batch script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180741/how-to-do-something-to-each-file-in-a-directory-with-a-batch-script)

Comment: and what's the problem? the script is not working? or you have distinct 64b and 32b machines?

Comment: I've added /f "usebackq delims=|" per the possible duplicate, no change. My problem is I cant get any output from the dumpbin command into my txt output. It outputs the command txt, it doesn't run the command.

Comment: aa yes you need `/f "usebackq tokens=* delims="`.Try to map `\\qaloan010\c$\` as a drive letter.Not sure if dir command will access the path like that.

Comment: You need to map the unc path to a drive letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the right combination.

```
for /f %%f in ("\\qaloan010\c$\temp\bin64\*.*") do dumpbin /HEADERS %%f | find "machine">>output.TXT
```

> 8664 machine (x64)
>
> 8664 machine (x64)
>
> .....

The space in "program files" might have been causing a problem, or it might have been the "dir \b path" qualifier. The access over UNC via c$ works fine if you have appropriate permissions.

Comment: not space but the closing bracket...If you escape the bracket with "^" it should work.but it hit me when I saw your self-answer.