# Loop though multiple folders and xcopy to target

Tags: loops, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a windows batch to loop through multiple folders and copy *.txt from each to a single target folder. Here is where i have started:

```
set inbox=C:\Test\inbox
for %%i in (C:\Test\Archive\ C:\Test\temp\) do (xcopy %%i\*.txt %inbox%\)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this code :

```
@echo off
set source="C:\Test\Archive" "C:\Test\temp"
set Target=C:\Test\inbox
for %%i in (%source%) do (xcopy "%%~i\*.txt" "%Target%" /Y /I /D)
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution:

[How to do something to each file in a directory with a batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180741/how-to-do-something-to-each-file-in-a-directory-with-a-batch-script)

Basically, looks like the first parentheses part should be

```
('dir /b C:\Test\Archive\ C:\Test\temp')
```

I'm not sure how that works with two directories - I think it should work but may require doing two runs and merging results.