# SQLserver bulk upload with no admin rights

Tags: sql-server

I have access to a SQL server and my rights are extremely limited.

I have been tasked with uploading 180 flat files. However, I can’t write a tsql script for bulk insert as I can’t access the file stores programmatically and I can’t run PowerShell. This is all because of admin access which I am never going to get.

Is there a convenient way to do this via SSMS? Or is the only option to go through 180 files and use the task import wizard ?

Comment: If you have the command-line BCP utility installed, you could use that using a [`for` in a batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180741/how-to-do-something-to-each-file-in-a-directory-with-a-batch-script) to import each file.

Comment: could i run bcp through ssms to access files not on the server ?

Comment: You could run xp_cmdshell from an SSMS query window to launch BCP on the server if the files are available via a share but I wouldn't go there. You would need sysadmin to do that anyway.

Comment: I can’t use anything Xp because of the crazy admin rights

Comment: Ideally I was look for a bulk import from the SSMS as I can manually import files via the import and export wizard.

Comment: I can’t understand why I can’t use the same functionality that the import export wizard uses within sqlcmd when using SSMS

Comment: You can, with Powershell. Is SSIS an option?