# Iterate files and get creation date

Tags: batch-file

I am learning to write batch files scripts and to do this I am trying to create a batch script that asks for a path and iterates over each file, getting its creation date and renaming the file.

Right now I am able to iterate and echo the file name like this:

```
@echo off
set /p path="Enter the folder path: "
for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f in (`dir /b %path%`) do (
    echo %%f
)

pause
```

Now, the next step: How can I get the creation date from %%f? I am stuck at this and was not able to proceed from here.

Comment: Before you do anything else, you should absolutely change that variable name from `path` to something which isn't an important system variable name. Then you need to open a Command Prompt window, type `dir /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the usage information. Pay specific attention to the `/T` option, which gives you the option of choosing the `C`reation, last `A`ccessed, or last `W`ritten, timestamps.

Comment: Why the `|` for the delimiter option?

Comment: Why the `UseBackQ` option?

Comment: Squashman and Compo I used this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180741/how-to-do-something-to-each-file-in-a-directory-with-a-batch-script to check on how to do an iteration. That's why I have that delimiter and UseBackQ option.

Comment: You should when using your new found knowledge from the command help, also consider using the appropriate option to select only files, as opposed to both files and directories too! I would also recommend that you use the on site search facility, as renaming files according to their dates is not something which has never been asked or answered before.

Comment: @Compo I have been using your first comment and I managed to echo the date! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: The post you linked is awful syntax, regardless of the number of votes or reputation of the author. It should really read `for /f "eol=| delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /a:-d "c:\program files"') do echo %%f` That answer is poor, it includes directories as well as files, ignores any which could begin with a `;` character, delimits with a character which will never occur, _(harmless)_, and uses back quotes for no reason too!

Comment: ```for /f %%f in ('dir /b %path%') do (echo %%~tf)```?

Comment: Have you even looked at the previous comments @NekoMusume, it appears that you've missed some important points, actual or implied, from within them.