# Encrypt zip file in folder with PGP

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp

I have been testing with PGP command line to create a batch file that encrypts all zip files in a folder

So far I have tried

GPG -e -r username c:\foldername*.zip

But when I run the bat file nothing happens.

Do I need the path to where PGP is installed adding?

I would also like to delete the zip once it’s encrypted and on a previous batch file used -SDEL, will this work here

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gpg doesn't seem to work file wildcards. You should use `for` cycle, see this answer for the examples: [How to do something to each file in a directory with a batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180741/how-to-do-something-to-each-file-in-a-directory-with-a-batch-script)